# Calculate average of scores for subset of filters in an algolia query

Tags: algolia

I have a question on filter scoring in Algolia. I would like to get an average of scores of a subset of the filters and then sum it up to the scores from other filters.

I have an index called posts. It has 3 attributes for faceting:

1. freshnessHoursOld: string e.g. 429685
2. locations: array of strings e.g. [Melboure, Sydney, Perth]
3. ageRange: string e.g. 50plus

In my Algolia query, I assign scores as follows

```
freshnessHoursOld:429685<score=50> or freshnessHoursOld:429600<score=10> 
or location:Melboure<score=10> or location:Sydney<score=7> or 
location:Perth<score=5> or ageRange:50plus<score=40>
```

The problem is – if a post has a location array of [Melboure, Sydney, Perth], then all three of the locations scores will match and the score for location match will be 10+7+5. The ageRange and freshnessHoursOld scores will also be added depending on the match.

What I want is - if a post has a location array of [Melboure, Sydney, Perth], then an average of the 3 is assigned for the location matches i.e. (10+7+5) /3 or just the highest or lowest of the 3 is used as the score for the location component. The ageRange and freshnessHoursOld scores will then also be added depending on the match.

I am aware of the parameter **sumOrFiltersScores**. But setting it to false means it takes the highest amongst all parameters - location, ageRange, freshnessHoursOld. And setting it to true means that it sums up the scores from all filter matches.

But I want the want to be able to take the highest or lowest or an average of the subset of the parameters which in this case is an array of locations. And the other scores (ageRange and freshnessHoursOld) also get added to this value when a match occurs.

Comment: As of today this is not possible to do within an Algolia query.
Could you detail what you'd like to achieve with an average versus the sum or highest score?  
The idea behind this feature is to help you surface results that have the best match within your given filters; what would an average solve for you?

Comment: Thank you for your response @OlivierLance. You are correct in saying that the idea of the scoring is to surface the best possible match for the given filter. The issue is that I use several filters in my query. When there are many matches for a row for a filter, it tends to dominate the result set and is always at the top. If I could some how say that the maximum score for this filter, no matter how many matches, is X - that would help to reduce this issue.

Comment: What does the result look like if you move `freshnessHoursOld` out of your filter and at the top of your custom ranking, keeping only the `location`/`ageRange` weights in your filter?
It feels like it could give a similar but less "radical" result?